# Getting the source code of an html page (not just the html code)

Tags: c#, html

Good morning, 
I would like to be able to get the source code of a .html page ([like this one](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/conjugaison/verbe/manger.html)) as it is displayed when you press CTRL+U in the browser.

I tried to use this;

```
                string link = "https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/conjugaison/verbe/" + verbe + ".html";

                this.progressBar_loading.Maximum = 100;
                Uri url = new Uri(link);
                WebClient client = new WebClient();

                client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgressCallback);
                client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadCompleted);

                client.DownloadStringAsync(url);
```

But this returns only the HTML code and not the source code as you can see by doing ctrl+u

Do you have a way to retrieve that code?
Thank you

**EDIT :** 
For the difference, I make for example search in the source code (CTRL+U) "I eat" and I find it, whereas I do it in the code that my code gives me not find it, and the code is much bigger by doing ctrl +u

Comment: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> shows the _HTML_ source code.  It's the exact same thing you get from `WebClient`.  Are you seeing some kind of difference?

Comment: Keep in mind that in your example the word "eat" is a link, but the word "to" isn't, so in the HTML code it is something like "to <a href="....">eat</a>".